# Problem with links in Apache POI (Presentation) after merging several files (PPTX file crash)

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

I have a rather specific problem with links in my Java-generated presentation by Apache POI.
I'm creating a presentation, based on a certain template, adding text to the presentation at a certain place to become a link. I use the code, of course:

```
XSLFHyperlink link = run.createHyperlink();
link.setAddress("link to set");
```

(of course I change the link to set every time).
When I download and open such a presentation (it always consists of one slide) everything works fine.

I generate several such slides based on a certain pattern (I duplicate the original slide each time).
Still each downloaded presentation works correctly.
Then, using Apache POI, I link them together (I simply link all the slides together).
However, when I try to open such a file in PowerPoint, I get a corrupted file message. The message appears:

> Powerpoint found a problem with content filename.pptx
> Powerpoint can attempt to repair the presentation

When I use Repair, the presentation loads, all the data is there but the texts are no longer links. Yes, the formatting of the link remains (blue, with underline) but the link itself is no longer there.
In the code that generates the presentation for the test, I turned off the code responsible for adding the link and performed the whole operation again. Then the finished, linked presentation opens correctly, no errors appear. Hence my belief that the problem is in linking.

Does anyone have an idea how to remedy this and what could be the problem?

Comment: "Then, using Apache POI, I link them together (I simply link all the slides together)." How? Please show the code used for this.